# Spring - applicationContext.xml cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit

I have a Spring MVC application and a problem with JUnit tests combined with the file applicationContext.xml.

In my JUnit test class I write:

```
final ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
service = (TestServiceImpl) context.getBean("testServiceImpl");
```

The error I get is that aplicationContect.xml can not be found:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

But it exists in the WEB-INF folder.

So, what's wrong here? Why does the file not exist for the JUnit test?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You should keep your Spring files in another folder, marked as "source" (just like "src" or "resources").

WEB-INF is not a source folder, therefore it will not be included in the classpath (i.e. JUnit will not look for anything there).

Answer (score 48):

If you use maven, create a directory called `resources` in the main directory, and then copy your `applicationContext.xml` into it.

From your java code call:

```
ApplicationContext appCtx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

Comment: Thanks, I use maven and putting applicationContext.xml into resources solved my problem right away!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also, none of the other solutions mentioned here work for maven project in IntelliJ

Comment: How to change this behavior?

Comment: @duracell, thanks a lot. I have been constantly refactoring my applicationContext.xml to various locations but nothing worked. Your answer helped me

Answer (score 10):

I got the same error. 
I solved it moving the file `applicationContext.xml`in a

sub-folder of the `src`folder. e.g:

```
context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/com/ejemplo/dao/applicationContext.xml");
```

Comment: had is in src had to include the path like above

Answer (score 8):

The `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` isn't going to find the `applicationContext.xml` in your `WEB-INF` folder, it's not on the classpath. You could copy the application context into your classpath (could put it under `src/test/resources` and let Maven copy it over) when running the tests.

Answer (score 7):

I also found this problem. What do did to solve this is to copy/paste this file everywhere and run, one file a time. Finally it compiled and ran successfully, and then delete the unnecessary ones. The correct place in my situation is:
[image]

This is under the /src/ path (I am using Intellij Idea as the IDE). The other java source files are under /src/com/package/ path

Hope it helpes.

Answer (score 4):

This happens to me from time to time when using eclipse
For some reason (eclipse bug??) the "excluded" parameter gets a value *.* (build path for my resources folder)

Just change the exclusion to none (see red rectangle vs green rectangle)
I hope this helps someone in the future because it was very frustrating to find.

[image: excluded]

Answer (score 2):

Click on the `src/main/java` folder and right click and create the xml file. If you create the `application.xml` file in a subpackage other than `/`, it will not work.

Know your structure is look like this

```
package/
|  subpackage/
   | Abc.java
   | Test.java

/application.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SIZ8.jpg)

I was struggling since a couple of hours for this issue because i was putting that file under resources folder but it didn't help me, finally i realized my mistake.
Put it directly under src/main/java.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it worked by keeping file(applicationContext.xml) in the resources folder

```
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Create a Directory at the bottom of main directory named resources. That solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I placed the applicationContext.xml in the src/main/java folder and it worked

Answer (score 1):

I solved it moving the file spring-context.xml in a src folder. 
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-context.xml");

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by adding applicationContext.xml into jar/target/test-classes for Maven project. And use

```
        XmlBeanFactory bf = new XmlBeanFactory( new ClassPathResource(
                "/applicationContext.xml", getClass() ) )
```

instead of

```
        XmlBeanFactory bf = new XmlBeanFactory( new ClassPathResource(
                "/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml", getClass() ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

**My solution**: 
If you have no folder **WEB-INF** please put the file **applicationContext.xml** into the folder source(**src**).  [image]

Then **Java Project** can read file **applicationContext.xml** -> **getBean** -> perform your business.

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxly0.png)The solution is to place the xml file in resources folder(src->main-> resources) and use this object creation new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

Answer (score 1):

---

If You are Working in Intelij IDE and Maven then Make sure that the .xml file is in the resources folder

[image: Make Sure that config.xml is in the resources Folder]

Answer (score 0):

In Spring all source files are inside src/main/java.
Similarly, the resources are generally kept inside src/main/resources. 
So keep your spring configuration file inside resources folder.

Make sure you have the ClassPath entry for your files inside src/main/resources as well.

In .classpath check for the following 2 lines. If they are missing add them.

```
<classpathentry path="src/main/java" kind="src"/>
<classpathentry path="src/main/resources" kind="src" />
```

So, if you have everything in place the below code should work.

ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Module.xml");

Answer (score 0):

Please do This code - it worked

```
 AbstractApplicationContext context= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
```

o/w: Delete main method class and recreate it while recreating please uncheck Inherited abstract method its worked

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Netbeans, i solved my problem by putting the file in: Other Sources default package, then i called it in this way:

`ApplicationContext context =new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bean.xml");`

[resources folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcD0j.png)

Answer (score 0):

While working with Maven got same issue then I put XML file into `src/main/java` path and it worked.

```
ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to understand the `ApplicationContext`. It is an interface and it will have different implementations based on configuration.

As you are using `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");` , kindly pay attention to initial right hand-side , it says **ClassPathXmlApplicationContext** , so the **XML** must be present in the class path.
So drag your **applicationContext.xml** wherever it is to the src folder.

> Gist: **new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext** as the name
>   [ClassPathXml]will look for the **xml** file in the src folder of your
>   project, so drag your xml file there only.

**** `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`—Loads a context definition from an XML
file located in the classpath, treating context definition files as classpath
resources.

**** `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext`—Loads a context definition from an XML
file in the file system.

**** `XmlWebApplicationContext`—Loads context definitions from an XML file contained
within a web application.

Answer (score 0):

```
just change the containing package of your applicationContext.xml file.
 applicationContext.xml must be in src package not in your project package.
 e.g. 
     src(main package)
         com.yourPackageName(package within src)
         classes etc.
     applicationContext.xml(within src but outside of yourPackage or we can say 
                            parallel to yourPackage name)
```

Answer (score 0):

### your-module/src/applicationContext.xml

```
val context = ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml")
```

Check the directory path, the default path is `/src/` and not `/`.

GL

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue while working on a maven project, so I recreate the configuration file `spring.xml` in `src/main/java` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by moving the file applicationContext.xml in an src folder and main folder.
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-context.xml");

Answer (score 0):

Your can use "AnnotationConfigApplicationContext" instead of "ClassPathXmlApplicationContext".

```
ApplicationContext context=new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("config.xml");
```