# Springboot war in tomcat not working

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, war

I'm trying to deploy a war generated with springboot in Tomcat, in which I have succeeded previously, but can't figure out what is wrong this time.

The most important code is added:

**`config/AppConfig`**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Component
//@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.singleuseapps")
public class AppConfig {
```

**`LaptopsApplication`**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses =      {AppConfig.class,LaptopsApplication.class})
public class LaptopsApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.sources(LaptopsApplication.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(LaptopsApplication.class, args);
}
```

**`build.gradle`**

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.4.2.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'war'

springBoot{
   executable = true
}

jar {
    baseName = 'laptops'
}

war {
    baseName = 'laptops'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.0.9.Final'
compile("com.h2database:h2")
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
compile 'org.javassist:javassist:3.15.0-GA'
compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.31'
compile 'commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4'
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.10"
compile "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.6.0"
compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.6.0'
compile 'com.sun.mail:javax.mail'
compile( 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail')
}
```

Hope someone gets why I failed.

[edit]

Line in catalina.out

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.singleuseapps.LaptopsApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/singleuseapps/cart/TestMailController.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Comment: you should give the exact error

Comment: I get a 404 when testing the endpoint in tomcat

Comment: And you have no error in the deploy phase ?

Comment: check `catalina.out` for some exception stacktrace.

Comment: where can I find catalina.out? -edit found it

Comment: Anyway, is the `server.contextPath` key valued in your Spring Boot profile properties ?
You should always value it to have the same context path : embedded server or not.

Comment: You probably have to exclude embedded Tomcat.

Comment: Added line from catalina.out

Comment: @davidxxx what do you mean?

Comment: Did you check your folder structure and classpath configuration? Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/3907833/6372139?

Comment: Structure is good. Local run with gradle bootrun gives no problems, but creating a war and using that in tomcat does.

Answer (score 0):

You should:

- remove @Component from AppConfig (it's already annotated with @Configuration)
- remove .configure method from LaptopsApplication, it's already annotated with @SpringBootApplication and is automatically a configuration class you don't need to add it again
- Ensure your controller class is in the package specified by your two @ComponentScan annotations (you probably just need the one on your main app class)